# How to extract clumped data from a 2D Array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a 1024x1024 array, of binary values 0 or 1, generated from a noise algorithm The 1s are always clumped in groups.
Visualizing it, it's like a plane of 0s with islands of 1s.

I want to extract any and each island of 1s into a new List (I happen to be using C#, but any container will do). An island is considered separate if none of its points 3x3 neighbours overlaps another island.

This sounds like it might be a common problem, but I don't know the name of any candidate algorithms to search for.

I'm doing it brute-force at the moment by checking every point and its neighbours that touch.

Any faster ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: [Flood-Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) each "1" to get the "island" it belongs to. Repeat for all 1's. Complexity is linear in the size of your matrix.

Comment: Thanks… exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

[Flood-Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) each "1" to get the "island" it belongs to. Repeat for all 1's. Complexity is linear in the size of your matrix.

An efficient pseudo code could be:

```
 1. set <- new Set
 2. for each cell (i,j) in matrix, if matrix[i][j] == 1:
     2.1. set.add(i,j)
 3. while set is not empty:
   3.1. island <- floodFill(i,j) // start flood fill from i,j
   3.2. set.removeAll(island) //remove already found 1's
   3.3. yield island
```